# PyQgis, styling vector layers in different canvas

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a QGIS plugin and I need some help with styling layers in different canvas objects.

In my dialog window I've got two QgsMapCanvas objects `canvas1` and `canvas2`. Layers from registry are loaded to both objects (the same list of layers).

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    # appending layer to list
canvas1.setLayerSet(list)
canvas2.setLayerSet(list)
```

Now in both canvas objects I've got the same map composition.
Next I want to change layer style only in `canvas1`. I've tried:

```
layers = canvas1.layers()
# get polygon layer
layer = layers[0]
# set properties
properties = {"color": "255,0,0", "outline_color": "255,0,255"}
s = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple(properties)
layer.setRendererV2( QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(s))
```

But this layer style is changed in all of the canvas objects (`canvas1`, `canvas2` and main canvas in Qgis).

How could I change styles for only one canvas in the most efficient way?

Comment: Should `layer = layer[0]` be `layer = layers[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is uncomplete and not well formated. However, this adaptation seems to work as it is espected:

```
canvas1 = iface.mapCanvas()

layers = []

n = canvas1.layerCount()

for i in range(n):
    layers.append(canvas1.layer(i))

canvas2 = canvas1

properties = {"color": "255,0,0", "outline_color": "255,0,255"}

symbol = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple(properties)

renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(symbol)

layers[1].setRendererV2(renderer)

layers[1].triggerRepaint()

iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layers[1])
```

After loading three times the **world_borders** shapefile at the Map View of QGIS,  the code was run  in the  Python Console. Only the `layer[1]` had the renderer (`layer[0]` was unmarked to facilitate visualization).

[image]

Comment: I know that layer can be load three times, but I don't want to do this. I want to set multiple renderers to single layer, each renderer for different canvas.

Comment: It was only an example. Now, it's more clear your requirement. However, edit your post to complete and put the correct format in your code. Thanks.